# How to make Visual Studio auto-formatter respect JSDoc comments?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, code-formatting, jsdoc

Visual Studio 2010 seems to break JSDoc-style comments when auto-formatting a Javascript file.

E.g.

```
/**
 * Important comment
 */
```

becomes

```
/**
* Important comment
*/
```

after formatting the document.

Is there a way to fix this - customize VS, use an extension etc.?

Answer (score -1):

You could avoid formatting the JavaScript code on enter:
1. Go to Tools -> Options
2. Text Editor | JScript | Formatting 
3. Uncheck Format Completed on Enter

Comment: Thank you. However, I do want my files to be formatted. I am quite used to hitting Ctrl+E, D regularly. I just want it done right.